# How to make each worker work with Map Channel?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, worker

My Snippet code:

**Main Worker**:

```
func Workergrab(m map[int][][]string, ch chan [][]string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for y := 1993; y <= 2014; y++ {
        ch <- m[y]
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

**Worker1**:

```
fmt.Println(<-ch)
```

Ok here was what i want to do

```
-> Main-Worker grabbing map data from m[y] and send it over to channel
-> Worker1 do get data from channel that main worker send at same time depend on y
```

I already tryed above, worker1 only show me m[1993] data. **Messed**

I was wondering using map channel, but not sure how make map channel.
I think messed up in channel thing...,
I wonder how i can make channel of
map[int][][]string so my worker1 will catch data from channel for each ID "1993", "1994" etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your code throw `all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` error; It means both of goroutines are ended or waited on writing/reading part forever.

`Workergrab` tries to send more than one value to the `ch` channel but `Worker1` only prints one `ch` value and finishes its work. So changing `Worker1` as the following can solve the problem:

```
func Worker1(ch chan [][]string) {
    for {
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
    }
}
```